# How to merge a series of observables within observables

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to refactor some code I wrote a while back to merge all my observables to receive a chat object at the same time. I'm using angular and ionic and firebase.

```
 this.userAsync = this.chatsProvider.getMyUserChatsGrpID().mergeMap(grpIDs=> {
  if (grpIDs.length > 0) {

    return Observable.combineLatest(
      grpIDs.map((grpID) => this.chatsProvider.getGroupObjectAsync(grpID.$key).map(grpObject => {
          grpObject.object = grpObject;
          grpObject.memberProfiles = this.chatsProvider.getMemberProfiles(Object.keys(grpObject.members))
          grpObject.latestMessage = this.chatsProvider.getLatestConversation(grpID.$key, grpObject.lastChecked)
          grpObject.unreadMessages = this.chatsProvider.getUnreadMessageCount(grpID.$key, this.profileService.getUIDString())
        return grpObject
      })),
    )
  } else {
    return Observable.of([])
  }
```

Currently such code would return the required object however, grpObject.memberprofiles, .lastestMessage, .unreadMessages are returned as observables which i then have to unwrap using an async pipe. Is there a way to convert it all to get back the item as one observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you wanting to achieve correctly, i.e. an observable of groups with all the group data (memberProfiles etc.) unwrapped, I think you need to add in another combineLatest then put the three observables in there.

So inside the grpIDs.map loop you'd want this

```
return this.chatsProvider.getGroupObjectAsync(grpID.$key).combineLatest(
  this.chatsProvider.getMemberProfiles(Object.keys(grpObject.members)),
  this.chatsProvider.getLatestConversation(grpID.$key, grpObject.lastChecked),
  this.chatsProvider.getUnreadMessageCount(grpID.$key, this.profileService.getUIDString()),
  /* Function which gets passed all the latest observable values for you to merge together*/
  (group, members, latestConversation, unreadMessageCount) => {
    return { group, members, latestConversation, unreadMessageCount };
  }
)
```

Note that I've changed the object properties.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Use toArray() operator. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray

```
let obs1$= Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3);
let obs2$= Rx.Observable.of('A','B','C');

obs2$.concat(obs1$).toArray().subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: But I still need my grpID.$key to generate the rest of the observables